# Build a SQLite database from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, build, msbuild

My desktop app includes a SQLite database it uses internally. The contents of this database are stored in .SQL (text) files so that the entire DB can be recreated from scratch based on the source files. Running these scripts in the correct order is what I refer to as a "database build" in this context.

I am looking for ways to **integrate this DB build into a Visual Studio solution**. The ideal might be:

- DB build is automatically re-run during a solution build whenever any .SQL file has changed, or if the target database does not exist
- IDE integration - edit .SQL files right there inside VS2015
- External program `sqlite3.exe` needs to be called to process each .SQL file
- The output database file is deposited in the `Debug\bin` folder (or `Release`) just like any other build output
- Processing errors captured in the Output pane

In other words - it behaves like a standard C# or C++ etc. project and build.

---

The only way I have turned up so far to do this might be to create an MSBuild script / project file. That may work but is not necessarily more advantageous than just running a batch file, and seems like it would lack IDE integration.

I was hoping there might be an existing VS project type which would accommodate this, but if it exists I haven't figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

> Build a SQLite database from Visual Studio?

If I understand you correct, you can include your database file in your project. Set the type to `Content` and CopyToOutputDirectory to `Copy if newer`, that will make sure the file is copied to your output directory and you can edit .SQL files inside VS2015.

Unload your project and add following into the project file `.sqlproj`:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="test.sql">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

See the [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39073759/how-to-add-sqlite-db-into-c-net-project) for some more details.

Hope this helps.